# how to change the color of circle to back with original color on clicking of another circle in D3 Js chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a D3 JS chart which draws Circle for each Class and radius for each circle is NoOfStudents in that particular class.

I added a Click event, which will change the color of circle from "black" to "lightcoral".

I would like the functionality that if I click on 2nd circle (after clicking of 1st circle), then rest all circles should return back to original "black" color.

How to achieve this? Thanks!

```js
//data
let data = [{ "noOfStudent": 40, "class": "Class 1" }, { "noOfStudent": 30, "class": "Class 2" }, { "noOfStudent": 20, "class": "Class 3" }];
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scalePoint().range([0, width]).padding(0.4);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("style", "outline: thin solid red;")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// get and format the data
data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.noOfStudent = +d.noOfStudent;
});

// Scale the range of the data in the domains
x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.class; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.noOfStudent; }) * 1.2]);

// append the rectangles for the bar chart
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.class); })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.noOfStudent); })
    .attr("r", function (d) { return d.noOfStudent; })
    .text(function (d) { return d.noOfStudent; })

    .on("click", function (d) {
        d3.select(this).attr('r', d.noOfStudent)
            .style("fill", "lightcoral")
    });

// add the x Axis
svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// add the y Axis
svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

Comment: on click, select all circles, colour them black, then select this circle colour this lightcoral

Comment: there is a API call in each circle selection. I think select all circle will have problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the circles a class to select them later :

```
.attr("class", "bar allCircles") //i didnt use 'bar' on purpose as you may have used it elsewhere
```

Separate the click function and, as I mentioned in the comments, colour all circles black, then the clicked circle lightcoral :

```
circles.on("click", function (d) {
        d3.selectAll('.allCircles').style('fill','black'); //fill all circles black
        d3.select(this).style("fill", "lightcoral"); //then fill this circle lightcoral
    });
```